# How to change the start attribute in ordered lists in tinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

Is it possible to add a button to the toolbar to change the start of the ordered lists in TinyMCE like this? (without viewing the source)

Title

1. List item 1
2. List item 2

Another title

3. List item 3
4. List item 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lists plugin has the ability to add an option to the context menu to access a list properties dialog (called `lists`) where you can select the starting number for the list.  For example:

```
contextmenu: "link image imagetools lists table"
```

Here is a working example in TinyMCE Fiddle:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/hlhaab

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. Do you know where they have docs for this?